# VBA An Object's instance

Tags: vba, excel, instance

Here is a question on VBA

I just cannot grasp clearly what is an instance of an object i've searched my VBA books and i have not found a clear answer. Phrases like:

- An instance of Word
- An instance of the class module
- The procedure declares an object Employee as a new instance of clsEmployee.

For me an object i mean if a Range("A1") is Set then what can possibly change and how we can tell for example if we have 10 loop iterations that change the value of Range A1 object an instance from another instance?

I' ve even heard instance of a variable!

**Thank you for watching my question**

Comment: Have you heard of the Object Browser? In VBEditor press F2 and you've got a list of all the Objects. It's a bit unclear to me what you are asking here, can you be more specific ?

Comment: Can you try to rephrase your question so that it is coherent? Exactly what is your specific question here?

Comment: Yes! Of course i use the Object Browser all the time!!! I will explain you what i mean...I constantly see books saying phrases like: by a running instance of Excel,    Formally "instance" is synonymous with "object", as they are each a particular value (realization), and these may be called an instance object; "instance" emphasizes the distinct identity of the object. The creation of a realized instance is called instantiation,    If multiple instances of WinWord.exe are found and my question is What do we mean when we say Instance of an Object or Variable in VBA

Comment: I just cannot locate a clean cut answer...

Comment: Yes i'm sorry I just cannot understand what is an instance of an object in VBA and how we can tell one instance from another (since they are many) i am searching for hours

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx

Comment: You are an instance of a person, you are not an instance of a bird. You are not the only person ever made though, there are other instances of a person.

Comment: Dear Alex. K since i am in complete darkness of the issue my search has led me again to this site but can you please explain what in common does a class and an instance have? Can we define an instance only in a class module that is why you pointed me towards that source or we can define an instance in a module to? For all i know you can write Set Word1 = New Word.Application in a module..Thank you

Comment: `Set Word1 = New Word.Application` is perfectly legal in both a class module and regular module.

Comment: Yes what is the instance so i know how to recognise her and grab her with my code....   1. Is it the statement you have given me above: Set Word1 = New Word.Application  2. Is the instance created when this statement is executed 3. Can the instance be captured by code?

Comment: The actual instance of the object is some block of memory in your system.  After calling `Set Word1 = New Word.Application`, `Word1` now contains a pointer to that block of memory.  For practical purposes, `Word1` is the "thing you want to grab with your code."  If you are having trouble with a specific application of this concept, I would recommend that you ask another question with the details of your actual problem.

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant As you have not accepted an answer yet, is there anything more that you do not understand?

Comment: Just a second some clients came in sorry and the want an invoice sorry people these thing happen!! just a min so i come back and read vote

Comment: At last i understand: the blueprint (Class module) instantiates-is called by Set Word1 = New Word.Application and an object is created according to the blueprints(class module we have written) in this case Word1!!! Thank you all guys for your presice answers and powerful patience you made a very happy man!

Comment: Yes now i understand better the class are the blueprint held in the container, module designed to have the class and is called class module! You declare it as a variable and then call it with the        Set Word1 = New Word.Application which creates an instance of the class modules...an instance of the blueprints and this is met with a  place pointed to my memory for that instance. The object which is custom made i can grab it using the Word1. This is the custom made object. Thank you all!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"An instance is a specific realization of any class..." [Instance (computer science) on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_%28computer_science%29)

```
Sub Example()
    Dim Word1 As Word.Application
    Dim Word2 As Word.Application
    Dim Word3 As Word.Application

    'Instantiate the first instance of a Word application
    Set Word1 = New Word.Application

    'Instantiate the second instance of a Word application
    Set Word2 = New Word.Application

    'Point our third Word object variable to the existing instance created above
    Set Word3 = Word1

End Sub
```

The above code contains **three object variables** (`Word1`, `Word2`, `Word3`) derived from **a single class** (`Word.Application`) representing **two distinct instances** (`Word1` and `Word3` point to the same instance and `Word2` points to the second instance).

---

It is important to note that the line `Set Word3 = Word1` does not copy the contents of the `Word1` object instance to `Word3`.  `Word1` really only contains a pointer to a location in memory where the object resides.

The line `Set Word3 = Word1` is saying copy the memory pointer from variable `Word1` into variable `Word3`.  So any change you make to the `Word1` object instance will be reflected in the `Word3` object instance...because they are **both pointing to the same instance**.

In example form:

```
Set Word3 = Word1

Word1.Visible = True
Debug.Print Word1.Visible  'outputs True
Debug.Print Word3.Visible  'outputs True

Word1.Visible = False
Debug.Print Word1.Visible  'outputs False
Debug.Print Word3.Visible  'outputs False
```

Comment: +1 as you distinguished the difference between making memory and instantiation of an object.

Comment: So to get this straight...Dim Word1 as Word.Application is not an instance right? The instance is the Set Word1 = New Word.Application or better the object that is created by the above statement?

Comment: `Dim Word1 as Word.Application` creates a variable named `Word1` of `Word.Application` data type. It does not instantiate it. It simply reserves some memory for this variable. The `Set Word1 = new Word.Application` instantiates (creates) an instance of `Word.Application` which you can refer to in your human-readable code by using the `Word1` variable.

Comment: Behind the scenes, the variables `Word1` and `Word3` really just store a pointer to a location in memory.  A common beginner mistake is to think that `Set Word3 = Word1` is copying the contents of `Word1` into `Word3`.  It is not.  So any change you make to the object instance represented by `Word1` will affect `Word3` because they are in fact the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you mention any object in your code, either an object or a Variable, you have to instantiation it.

This means you have to create an instance (an existence of the object of variable).

for every time in your could you call `Dim x as something` you have not creating what something is, you are creating a new instance of a something, a whole new entity that takes on the form of whatever you specify it to be.

So by saying `Dim strSample As String` you are creating a new instance of an object or variable that takes on the properties and methods of being a `String`

In other works an instance is an existance of an object or variable, every time you have an object or a variable it exists, and in order to exist it has it's own instance.

You are creating a new object. or instantiation

You are an instance of a person, you are *not* an instance of a bird. You are not the only person ever made though, there are other instances of a person.

Comment: I think your answer is very confusing and inaccurate. You make room in memory by saying `Dim x as something` and you instantiate that object to an instance by saying `Set x = new something`.

Comment: @mehow not all classes are required to be set as a new instance, I can use `Dim strSample As String` and it will create a new instance of a string called `strSample`, even if blank.

Comment: String in VBA is a value type so partially true you instantiate it in one go, but **objects** are reference types which requires to declare and instantiate (2 actions although can be done in one go)

Comment: @mehow an object is anything, An object can be a variable, function, or data structure and you can assign either a reference type or a value type to a variable of the object data type, as it always holds a pointer to the data, never the data itself.

Comment: In VBA an object is none of those things, its always nothing or an instance of a class.